# how combine 2 query into 1 query with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

First, sorry for my bad english.

Here's my data mysql:

```
id | tx_command  | tx_status
-----------------------------
1  | postpaid    | OK
2  | prepaid     | OK
3  | cek         | OK
4  | cek         | NOK
5  | view_voucher| OK
6  | postpaid    | NOK
7  | prepaid     | NOK
```

Here is problem and hard for me. I want to show data based *- Tx_command 'postpaid and prepaid' with tx_status 'ok'*, then even though the postpaid or prepaid tx_command but his tx_status 'NOK' then doesn't show.
- And the second is that I want to show tx_command 'cek' with tx_status 'NOK', in other words if tx_command 'cek' and tx_status 'NOK' then doesn't show.

it's possible if whether it can be if both are made into one query?

Comment: Update your that two query also which one you tried..

Comment: updated @PiyushGupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an `OR` condition...

Something like this

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   <your-table>
WHERE 
  (tx_command = 'prepaid' AND tx_status = 'OK') OR
  (tx_command = 'prepaid' AND tx_status = 'OK') OR
  (tx_command = 'cek' AND tx_status = 'NOK')
```